# Можно ли хранить значение обьекта в виде обьекта?

Tags: javascript, frontend

Корректно ли хранить следующую структуру обьектов:

```
let first_obg{
    name:name,
    password:password,
    comment:comment_obg
},
```

где

```
comment_obg={
    author:author;
    text:text
}
```

Т.е обьект в обьекте? Правильно ли так хранить информацию?

Comment: абсолютно корректно, можете в браузере в консоли разработчика вывести обьект window, посмотреть его структуру.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эмм... напишу подобный объект от балды...

```
var document = {
  'body': {
    'className': {
      'bubu': [
        {'style': {'backround-color': 'red', 'font-size': '20px'} },
        {'style': {'backround-color': 'red', 'font-size': '20px' *ОТМЕЧЕННОЕ МЕСТО*} }, 
      ],
      'kuku': {'style': {'width': '50px'} }
    },
  }
}
```

Если захочется добавить в отмеченном месте, скажем, `color: blue;` надо будет записать:

```
document.body.className.bubu[1].style.color = "blue";

//Написанное конкретно про объект из примера, а не рабочий код для классов
```

Кажется знакомым?)) JS построен на этом